# Saving a variable in a text file

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to save variable (including its values) into a text file, so that the next time my program is opened, any changes will be automatically saved into the text file
.For example:

```
    balance = total_savings - total_expenses
```

How would I go about saving the variable itself into a text file instead of only its value?
This section is for the register page

```
    from tkinter import *
    register = Tk()
    Label(register, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
    Label(register, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

    e1 = Entry (register)
    e2 = Entry (register, show= "*")

    e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    username = e1.get()
    password = e2.get()


    button1 = Button(register, text = "Register", command = register.quit)
    button1.grid(columnspan = 2)
    button1.bind("<Button-1>")

    import json as serializer
    with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(username, f)
    with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(password, f)


    register.mainloop()
```

Altered code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    register = Tk()
    Label(register, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
    Label(register, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    e1 = Entry (register, textvariable=username)
    e2 = Entry (register, textvariable=password, show= "*")

    e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


    button1 = Button(register, text = "Register", command = register.quit)
    button1.grid(columnspan = 2)
    button1.bind("<Button-1>")

    import json as serializer
    with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(username.get(), f)
    with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(password.get(), f)
```

Log in code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    login = Tk()
    Label(login, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
    Label(login, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    i1 = Entry(login, textvariable=username)
    i2 = Entry(login, textvariable=password, show = "*")

    i1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    i2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def clickLogin():
            import json as serializer
            f = open('godhelpme.txt', 'r')
            file = open('some_file.txt', 'r')
            if username == serializer.load(f):
                    print ("hi")
            else:
                    print ("invalid username")
                    if password == serializer.load(file):
                            print ("HELLOOOO")
                    else:
                            print ("invalid password")



    button2 = Button(login, text = "Log In", command = clickLogin)
    button2.grid(columnspan = 2)


    login.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to know the variable's name at compilation time. So all you need to do is:

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("balance %d" % balance)
```

This can be more convenient to manage using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) object for mapping names to values.

You may also want to read about the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) modules which provide easy serialization of objects such as [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

The way to use a serializer such as [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is:

```
import pickle as serializer

balance = total_savings - total_expenses 
with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump( balance, f)
```

You can change `pickle` to `json` in the provided code to use the other standard serializer and store objects in `json` format.

### **Edit:**

In your example you're trying to store text from `tkinter`'s `Entry` widget. Read about it [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

What you probably miss is using a StringVariable to capture the entered text:

Create `StringVar` for variables:

```
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
```

Register StringVar variables to Entry widgets:

```
e1 = Entry (register, textvariable=username)
e2 = Entry (register, textvariable=password, show= "*")
```

Save content using `StringVar` in two seperate files:

```
import json as serializer
with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump(username.get(), f)
with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump(password.get(), f)
```

If you want them in the same file create a mapping (`dict`) and store it:

```
import json as serializer
with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
    serializer.dump(
        {
            "username": username.get(),
            "password": password.get()
        }, f
    )
```

### **Edit 2:**

You were using the serialization **before** entering text. Register a `save` function (that can later exit) to the register button. This way it will be called **after** the user clicked it (that means the content is already there). Here is how:

```
from tkinter import *

def save():
    import json as serializer
    with open('godhelpme.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(username.get(), f)
    with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        serializer.dump(password.get(), f)
    register.quit()

register = Tk()
Label(register, text ="Username").grid(row = 0)
Label(register, text ="Password").grid(row = 1)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

e1 = Entry (register, textvariable=username)
e2 = Entry (register, textvariable=password, show= "*")

e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

# changed "command"
button1 = Button(register, text = "Register", command = save)
button1.grid(columnspan = 2)
button1.bind("<Button-1>")
register.mainloop()
```

What happened before was the save-to-file process happened immediately before the user inserts any data. By registering a function to the button click you can ensure that only when the button is pressed, the function executes.

I **strongly** suggest you play with your old code in a debug environment or use some prints to figure out how the code works.

Comment: Thank you so so much :) i'm a total newbie at this as you can tell

Comment: We were all new to programming once. You can accept the answer if it's valid.

Comment: @honeybadger how did you end up serializing your data (string? dictionary? list?)? I'd suggest you print the data or use a debugger. if there is a problem open another question after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I used the code that you posted me to do it, but the only problem would be the quotation marks..

Comment: @honeybadger they are **not** a problem as long as you use the same mechanism (`json`/`pickle`/your own). What you get from `serializer.load` is what you put in `serializer.dump(something, f)`. For more information read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization . Did you try and debug your code using a debugger? Did you try and print the variables to see what values they hold? Share the attempts you made to understand the code.

Comment: I've tried debugging the program online but they basically just run the program till it stops at the error. I've been looking for solutions but none seem to work, I was trying to just strip the word from the text file but that doesn't seem to be working either. I've even tried adding the quotation marks inside the coding as text so that it might somehow be able to log in but that just caused a syntax error

Comment: @honeybadger Best advice I can give you to become way more productive and flatten your learning curve is to download and use PyCharm community edition which is free. Use it to write and debug your code: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-educational/download/ . You can get a free copy of the professional edition for educational purposes if you're a student. Disclaimer: I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is often not a good practise to store a variable in a `.txt` file, Python has a very nice library as [Pickle](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fpickle.html&ei=N-5NVcfxOJPguQTAooDADQ&usg=AFQjCNE13YnDcbSQzF3bDrL6gKHPVeKsRA&sig2=Bz1BFSbhNawQ7yU9Mv_Eig&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E&cad=rja). However still you can analyse both methods and choose one.

Method 1:

Using a `.txt` file:

```
with open("variable_file.txt", "w") as variable_file:
    variable_file.write("a = 10")
```

And while retrieving the value you can use:

```
with open("variable_file.txt", "r") as variable_file:
    for line in variable_file.readlines():
        eval(line.strip())
```

Method 2:

Using the Pickle module:

```
import pickle

a = 10

pickle.dump( a, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )

#Load the variable back from the pickle file.

a = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

Comment: would this work the same if I were to save my user's username and password as variables?